# File permissions for shared hosting environment

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, access-control-list, shared-hosting

I am trying to set-up a shared hosting environment where users are given SFTP access to one or multiple folders. Consider the following scenario:

`/var/www/` holds several directories that represent domains. The users can add, modify or delete files in directories based on ACLs, so user `john` can have full access to `/var/www/domain1.com` and `/var/www/domain2.org` but not `/var/www/domain3.de`. At the same time of course, the web server must be able to read the files within all directories.

What I do not fully understand is how to secure everything in such a way, that

- all users are jailed to `/var/www/` and only see the domains (subfolders) they are allowed to see
- the Apache user `www-data` has only read access to all folders
- PHP has write access to some folders such as a user uploads folder or a log folder within `/var/www/domain/`
- new files uploaded via SFTP obtain the correct permissions automatically and the user is able to specify what folder is writable by PHP without being accessible by other shared hosting users

With PHP I mean a PHP-FPM instance with each domain being a separate entry in `pool.d` and the user freely configurable.

My ideas so far were to add a group called `sftp` and configure `sshd` to jail users belonging to the group `sftp` to `/var/www/`, allow password authentication for them and add `ForceCommand internal-sftp`. Then I would set default ACLs recursively for the folders inside `/var/www/` so that the right users have access to the right directories.
But what do I set as owning user and group for the folders? Do I have to adjust the umask? What is the appropriate user and group for the respective PHP-FPM pool instance?

Comment: I assume I can make all folders in `/var/www/` owned by `root:www-data` with group sticky and read permission (and execute for directories), does that sound like a good plan? And for the directories that have to be written by PHP, I can tell the user to make them group writable. PHP would run as www-data then.

Comment: OK, guess that won't work, as `chmod` changes the umask when ACLs are being used as far as I understand.